# Xml Reading Issue using Xdocument

Tags: c#, xml

Below is the sample xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UsersList>
  <User>
    <Name>sam&Tim</Name>
    <Address>21, bills street, CA</Address>
   <Issues>"Issues1", "Issues2"</Issues>
  </User> 
</UsersList>
```

c#:

```
string xml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"E:\Sample.xml"); 
                xml = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(xml, "<(?![_:a-z][-._:a-z0-9]*\b[^<>]*>)", "&lt;");

                XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
```

i need to convert the special charecters (<,>,",',&) and i am using the above regex. but parse method throws an error. any help please how to resolve the issue

Comment: Why do you need to replace regular xml tags with &lt;?

Answer (score 0):

See your current code converts XML like this

```
&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
&lt;UsersList>
  &lt;User>
    &lt;Name>sam&Tim&lt;/Name>
    &lt;Address>21, bills street, CA&lt;/Address>
   &lt;Issues>"Issues1", "Issues2"&lt;/Issues>
  &lt;/User> 
&lt;/UsersList>
```

Whereas Parse is looking it like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UsersList>
  <User>
    <Name>sam and Tim</Name>
    <Address>21, bills street, CA</Address>
   <Issues>"Issues1", "Issues2"</Issues>
  </User> 
</UsersList>
```

and thus you should not be converting `<` to `&lt;` but XML contains sam&Tim would not allow you to Parse it. thus you can use

```
xml = xml.Replace("&", " n ");//n or and or some other char or string you want
```

instead of

```
xml = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(xml, "<(?![_:a-z][-._:a-z0-9]*\b[^<>]*>)", "&lt;");
```

Hope this will help you to parse it.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the help. i have question with the below code       `&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
&lt;UsersList>
  &lt;User>
    &lt;Name>sam&Tim&lt;/Name>
    &lt;Address>21, bills street, CA&lt;/Address>
   &lt;Issues>"Issues1", "Issues2"&lt;/Issues>
  &lt;/User> 
&lt;/UsersList>`                                                                                                how to use this encoded text in the Xdocument.parse or Xdocument.load? any suggestions please

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try with:

```
string xml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"E:\Sample.xml"); 
xml = ReplaceXMLEncodedCharacters(xml)

public string ReplaceXMLEncodedCharacters(string input)
{
    const string pattern = @"&#(x?)([A-Fa-f0-9]+);";
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
    int offset = 0;
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        int charCode = 0;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(match.Groups[1].Value))
            charCode = int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value);
        else
            charCode = int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        char character = (char)charCode;
        input = input.Remove(match.Index - offset, match.Length).Insert(match.Index - offset, character.ToString());
    offset += match.Length - 1;
    }
    return input;
}
```

Comment: Hi Yanga, thank you for the input and if i need to include the below symbols what should i do? ®,°F  for example <value> Microsoft®</value>                        <temp> 20°F</temp> i need these symbols also to be taken care

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your original XML is **not a valid XML document**, because is contains an unescaped ampersand ('&') which is explicitly forbidden by the [standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/) that says

> The ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) must not appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters, or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section.

To make it valid, you must use &amp instead of a literal &. Trying to "correct" it is not practical and a totally bad idea in the general case, because you can never be sure, where in your XML & stands for a literal & and where it is part of an XML entity. If it were possible to distinguish these usages unambiguously, that rule could be embedded in XML parsers and we would not have to deal with it.

A valid, standard-conformant representation of your document would be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UsersList>
  <User>
    <Name>sam&amp;Tim</Name>
    <Address>21, bills street, CA</Address>
   <Issues>"Issues1", "Issues2"</Issues>
  </User> 
</UsersList>
```